# How can users post after posts of others?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I want to display an `add comment` button(like in here or FaceBook) for all of the users' posts.

As you can see in here, if you click "add comment" button, small input box opens and your comment appears right below where you add it with smaller size than normal posts.

I am confused about which language would be the best for this. I know a little about JavaScript and jquery but i think doing it with php is not possible. An idea or example to do that would be greatly helpful.

Comment: Just to clarify that almost everything is possible with php.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript shows the form field, than makes an Ajax call to the server when the person clicks the add content button.

The server saves the content to the database, and returns a success message.

If successful, the JavaScript shows the comment and hides the form fields.

Comment: +1. The sysetm can be implemented with no client-side script at all, just use a form for sending the data. And if javascript is available, do the post using AJAX and update the page with script.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript and jquery its a client side technologies. Php is a server side. You need a proper database design and can choose any sever technology you like.